# React-native textInput onFocus is not working

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make onFocus style for TextInput but no matter what I try it does not work,

Here is my current code

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './styles';

const Input = (props) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <TextInput
      onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
      style={focused ? styles.inputFocused : styles.input}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

I also tried to wrap it around TouchableOpacity and pass it setFocused function onPress, but it did not work either

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Do you think {...props} is overriding your function?

Comment: I tried to delete it but still not working

Comment: I don't think your code is wrong. It looks good

Comment: try log focused to check

Comment: I restarted app and u were right props were over writing my function but now I have problem on passing props

Comment: I think just bring ...props on your head component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your props override onFocus function just bring it on the head like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './styles';

const Input = (props) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
      style={focused ? styles.inputFocused : styles.input}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: This seems to not work. `onBlur` event isn't called when you touch outside the input box except for another input text or touchable areas.